# Why am I getting such random results when checking DNS?

Tags: php, dns, boolean

The code is as follows:

```
$domain = "fosajfjdkgdajfhsd.com";
$check1 = checkdnsrr($domain, "MX");
$check2 = checkdnsrr($domain, "A");
$check3 = (checkdnsrr($domain, "MX") || checkdnsrr($domain, "A"));
$check4 = !(checkdnsrr($domain, "MX") || checkdnsrr($domain, "A"));
die("{$check1} - {$check2} - {$check3} - {$check4}");
```

However when I check the output to see what it's returning, I get this:

```
 - 1 - 1 -
```

The domain obviously wouldn't exist, so I don't understand why checking the A record is returning true and checking the MX result doesn't give me anything at all. I don't understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: I suppose it could be a local routing aberration.  Have you tried adding a trailing period on the end of the domain to enforce its root?  A comment in the PHP manual for checkdnsrr() suggests that, ie. 'fosajfjdkgdajfhsd.com.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after browsing through all of the examples in the PHP.net documentation for `checkdnsrr()` I figured out that for A records you are still required to append a '.' to the end of the domain in order to check it validly. I figured PHP would automatically do that kind of thing for you, but whatever works. Results are as expected now.

Comment: Hah, I just left a comment with that suggestion.  I should have posted it as an answer  ;)

Comment: Yes you should have, lol. I noticed it there after posting this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ dig fosajfjdkgdajfhsd.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> fosajfjdkgdajfhsd.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39121
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fosajfjdkgdajfhsd.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fosajfjdkgdajfhsd.com.  0   IN  A   208.69.32.132

;; Query time: 121 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr  7 00:59:59 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

EDIT: Check your DNS provider.  Nowadays, lots of them will return their own A record so they can put ads in front of you eyes if the domain can't be resolved.  Breaks DNS, but pays the bills.

Comment: Ok, so typing random letters doesn't work. But I've been trying all sorts of other combinations and they all return the same result. I tried "gfsgfghghjggdajfhsd.bite" which cannot possibly exist because .bite is not even a valid domain extension, but I still get true for the A record.

Comment: +1, ISPs like Time Warner Cable (RoadRunner) by default give you a landing page if you try to return a domain that doesn't exist. I would be curious to see the dig output from your box, as Fred has provided. ($check2 returns false for me, on my work connection.)